# Difference between string and character vector in Matlab 2015

Tags: matlab

what is the difference between a string and a character vector in Matlab 2015? For example:

vc='hello world'         %1x11 character vector

str=string(vc)           %1x11 string instead of 1x1

Thank you for your help.

EDIT: sorry for my mistake, I use Matlab 2015, not 2016.

Comment: Hi @Poelie, the problem is that str=string(vc) is not 1x1 like in String vs. Character in MATLAB.

Comment: Check your code, I cannot reproduce this. Try running this: `vc='hello world';
str=string(vc);
size(str) % output: 1 1`

Comment: Hi @Poelie, maybe Matlab has a problem because it shows the following error "Warning: string is obsolete and will be discontinued.  Use char instead."

Comment: Run `which string.m`. What does it return?

Comment: @Poelie C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Production Server\R2015a\toolbox\matlab\codetools\@mtree\string.m  % mtree method

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi: That indicates you're running R2015a, not R2016.

Comment: Either that, or the path is wrongly set and the 2015a mtree string script has taken priority over the R2016b string script.

Comment: String objects (and the `string` function) were not introduced until R2016b. It was all character arrays before then.

Comment: Thank you very much @gnovice for your clarification.